# How can I notify that the `DataContext` was replaced?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datacontext

How can I notify that the `DataContext` was replaced? Say I have a `UserControl`:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl {
    ...
    void OnSomethingHappens_Change_DataContext () {
        DataContext = new MyViewModelType();
    }
}
```

When I call `OnSomethingHappens_Change_DataContext()` all bindings cease to function. My current workaround implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    ...
    void OnSomethingHappens_Change_DataContext () {
        DataContext = new MyViewModelType();            
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DataContext"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

But it feels awkward to make a `UserControl` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I tried:

```
    void OnSomethingHappens_Change_DataContext () {
        var oldDataContext = DataContext;
        DataContext = new MyViewModelType();
        OnPropertyChanged(new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(DataContextProperty, oldDataContext, DataContext));
    }
```

But it doesn't work, no idea why...

Comment: When you change a DataContext a propertychanged event is fired even without what you added. All bindings should get the new value. Could show how you bind to DataContext?

Comment: `DataContextChanged` event ?

Comment: Is it possible you get the initial value of DataContext through binding?

Comment: @stijn, what do I do in the `DataContextChanged` ? how do I raise it? (I can't raise it since it's not mine)

Comment: It is raised automatically when the DataContext is changed. What you do in it: depends on what you want to achieve. No idea why your bindings stop working, could be something in your code. Maybe you should show some relevant piece of that.